# How do I apply a new card back?

Tags: hearthstone

When a new ranked season started, I received a message that I had won a card back - a blue one.

How can I apply it?

Comment: Did you try looking at the Options menu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the game menu in the bottom right corner (the little cog wheel icon) and then select "Options". There you'll also find the screen to change your card back.

[image]